# WCF Contracts and Polymorphism with different namespaces: what gives?

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces, polymorphism

How do I perform polymorphism in a scenario like this:

if I have a class Dachshund in namespace Foo that is inherited from class Dog in namespace Bar:

```
namespace Bar
{
  public class Dog
  {
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Bark { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace Foo
{
  public class Dachshund : Dog
  {
    public int Length { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and I use Dachshund to do some dog stuff but pass it through wcf as a dog, what gives? some serialization issues:

```
[ServiceBehavior]
public class myWcfService : ImyWcfService
{
  [OperationBehavior]
  public Message GetDog()
  {
    var myDach = new Dachshund();
    // do some stuff with my dach
    return new Message { Dog = myDach as Dog, Message = "I'm sending a dog" };
  }
}

public class Message
{
  public Dog Dog { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need a `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dachshund))]`. Otherwise the DataContractSerializer does not know how to deal with that class and serializes it as just a Dog.

Comment: I added the attribute but it still won't send the contract.  I mapped the object value for value and that worked. That's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: it works for me if I add the `[ServiceKnownType]` attribute to the service **contract** (the interface, rather than the actual class). Have you tried that?

Comment: oh, dumb me, I was adding it to Dog class...

Comment: let me know if that fixed your problem and I can post a proper answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56309/discussion-between-chris-hayes-and-highcore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the [`[ServiceKnownType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute to your service **contract** (the **interface** that defines the service operations, rather than the service implementation (the actual class):

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Dachshund))]  // <- Add this attribute
public interface ImyWcfService
{
   //...
}
```

this will be enough for the DataContractSerializer to "know" your class and be able to properly serialize / deserialize it.